# Forcing light sleep mode in NodeMCU

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

The RTOS SDK docs have this sample C code:

```
wifi_set_opmode(NULL_MODE);    // set WiFi mode to null mode.
wifi_fpm_set_sleep_type(LIGHT_SLEEP_T); // light sleep
wifi_fpm_open();  
PIN_FUNC_SELECT(PERIPHS_IO_MUX_MTCK_U,3);
gpio_pin_wakeup_enable(13, GPIO_PIN_INTR_LOLEVEL);
wifi_fpm_set_wakeup_cb(fpm_wakup_cb_func1); // Set wakeup callback
wifi_fpm_do_sleep(0xFFFFFFF);
```

Does NodeMCU expose any of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to `wifi.sleep` implementation of nodemcu in [wifi.c](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/modules/wifi.c) :

```
//wifi.sleep()
static int wifi_sleep(lua_State* L)
{
...
    // set WiFi mode to null mode
wifi_set_opmode(NULL_MODE);
// set force sleep type
wifi_fpm_set_sleep_type(MODEM_SLEEP_T);
wifi_fpm_open();
wifi_fpm_do_sleep_return_value = wifi_fpm_do_sleep(FPM_SLEEP_MAX_TIME);
...
}
```

Then in order to call `wifi_fpm_set_sleep_type` with `LIGHT_SLEEP_T`, you will need to modify nodemcu and for wakeup you probably need call `wifi.sleep(0)` when input change.

Comment: Thanks!  What about gpio_pin_wakeup_enable?  I searched the nodemcu sources, the prototype isn't in it anywhere.  It is in 0.9.6 dev, looks like the lib it comes from is eagle.rom.addr.v6.ld.  The makefile for the latest sources reference eagle.rom.addr.v6.ld, so all I should need is the prototype declaration, and a few changes to wifi_sleep... right?

Comment: wifi.sleep doesn't seem to do anything, is that why it's undocumented?

Comment: There is a doc in the [pull request#725](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/725) and there is some discussion about it  in [issue#1115](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1115)